# Как привязать input к тексту?

Tags: javascript, html

Тоисть у меня есть input и мне нужно чтобы он активировался не отдельной клавишей а кликом по тексту. 
 //

```
<p>Наименование</p><p>Cтарая цена</p><p>Новая цена</p><p>Адресс</p>
    <table id="list"></table>
<div class = "type" id="calculating">
    <input type="submit" id="upbutton" value="&uarr;">
    <input type="submit" id="downbutton" value="&darr;">
```

Старая цена и новая цена тексты для обоих импутов.  //

Comment: Клик по тексту старая цена должен вызывать инпут upbutton по клику новой цены downbutton

Answer (score 0):

Используйте элемент `label` с атрибутом `for`.

```html
<p>Наименование</p>
<p><label for="upbutton">Cтарая цена</label></p>
<p><label for="downbutton">Новая цена</label></p>
<p>Адрес</p>
<table id="list"></table>
<div class="type" id="calculating">
  <input type="submit" id="upbutton" value="&uarr;" onclick="alert('upbutton')">
  <input type="submit" id="downbutton" value="&darr;" onclick="alert('downbutton')">
</div>
```